# Change text in AlertDialog at runtime

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, settext

I would like to change the text in an AlertDialog at runtime, but it´s not really working yet.

Since I´m using a custom layout I thought that I could do it like this,

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog_item_detail = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);   

LayoutInflater inflate_dialog = getLayoutInflater();
TextView mjollnir_descr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_item_descr);
mjollnir_descr.setText(R.string.item_detail_mjollnir_descr);        

dialog_item_detail.setIcon(R.drawable.item_clarity);
dialog_item_detail.setView(inflate_dialog.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog, null));     
dialog_item_detail.create();

dialog_item_detail.setTitle(R.string.dialog_item_detail_title_clarity);   
//dialog_item_detail.setCancelable(true);   
dialog_item_detail.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){               
   }   
   });   

dialog_item_detail.show();
```

but as mentioned above it´s not working. I´m always getting this error at the second line of the above code:

```
03-31 19:45:25.261: E/AndroidRuntime(781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 19:45:25.261: E/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-31 19:45:25.261: E/AndroidRuntime(781): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 19:45:25.261: E/AndroidRuntime(781):  at com.myapp.ItemsOverview.show_details_mjollnir(ItemsOverview.java:81)
```

Comment: Are you there, post your alert dialog complete code..I 'll show you How to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog_item_detail = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);   

    LayoutInflater inflate_dialog = getLayoutInflater();
View v=inflate_dialog.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog, null);
    TextView mjollnir_descr = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_item_descr);
    mjollnir_descr.setText(R.string.item_detail_mjollnir_descr);        

    dialog_item_detail.setIcon(R.drawable.item_clarity);
    dialog_item_detail.setView(v);     
    dialog_item_detail.create();

    dialog_item_detail.setTitle(R.string.dialog_item_detail_title_clarity);   
    //dialog_item_detail.setCancelable(true);   
    dialog_item_detail.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){               
       }   
       });   
dialog_item_detail.show();
```

---

You will get `NullPointerException` because your `TextView` is null.

Because you are not getting it from the inflatted view(i.e your customView) of dialog

i.e

try

```
TextView mjollnir_descr = (TextView)yourview. findViewById(R.id.dialog_item_descr);
```

here

`yourview` is the inflatted view for your dialog where your TextView reside

Comment: Well I thought that it´s working, but it isnt. `TextView mjollnir_descr = (TextView)inflate_dialog.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog, null).findViewById(R.id.dialog_item_descr);` I´m not etting any error, but the text just won´t change to the new one...

Comment: @f4bzen Don't inflate again...use Already inflated view. if you use second time it will create a new copy. so you are not changing the current copy text. so remove this inflate_dialog.inflate(R.layout.item_dialog, null), and use view that you have already inflatted

Comment: @f4bzen I have modified your code, Check it, if you have any doubts feel free to ask me